# Simple C array issues

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MEM_SIZE 16

typedef struct memory_contents{
 unsigned char mem[MEM_SIZE]; /* memory */
} mem;

mem init(char prog[]){
 mem chip = {prog};
 return chip;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 char memory[MEM_SIZE] = {0}; /* zero out whole array */
 mem chip = init(memory);

 printf("%d\n", chip.mem[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Am I right in thinking that what this code does (specifically, the init function) is try to put the address of the variable 'memory' into the struct's array? (and hence this is why it's printing a non-zero value)

What I'm trying to achieve is to initialise the struct such that the struct's mem array is the prog[] parameter. What's the preferred, or best, way of doing this? I could make the struct's mem a pointer to the first element of an array of size MEM_SIZE, but I feel that might cause problems: if I change the memory array in main later down the line, it'll change the values in chip's array too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the recommended way of doing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MEM_SIZE 16

typedef struct memory_contents{
 unsigned char mem[MEM_SIZE]; /* memory */
} mem_t;

mem_t* init (char* arr)
{
    mem_t* info = (mem_t*) malloc (sizeof (mem_t));
    if (!info)
    return NULL:    /* No memory */

    memcpy (&info->mem, arr, MEM_SIZE);
    return info;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char memory[MEM_SIZE] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,0};
    mem_t* chip = init (memory);
    if (!chip)
    return ENOMEM;

    printf("values: %d %d\n", chip->mem[0], chip->mem[1]);

    if (chip)
    free (chip);

    return 0;
}
```

one more point to note: Try not have the structure field member name and structure name same. They might cause a lot of conflicts.

Comment: Yeah, my bad for the two 'mem's. Is the appended _t in mem_t the accepted way people differente a type (size_t, time_t for example)?

Comment: That depends on what coding formats (or guidelines) you are following. I usually prefer this (usually followed in lot of *NIX code): typedef struct foobar_st {int a;} foobar_t;

Comment: No, names ending in `_t` are reserved by standards and it is likely you will conflict with an OS implementation at some point. So it is best to avoid them.

Comment: I recommend against the casts, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the struct's `mem` pointer because it's not a normal pointer -- the name `mem` is just a name for the address of that field. Don't initialize arrays using `{ ... }` notation; it's just hard to read and confusing (it certainly confused me...). Use `memcpy` instead.

---

Edit:

Your code doesn't compile with my compiler:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char []' to 'char'
    This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or function-style cast
```

(The error is at this line: `mem chip = {prog};`)

I was at first confused at why your code even compiled, and after checking it here, it makes sense: Like I stated above, you're trying to assign an array/pointer to `mem`, which is not allowed because `mem` is simply a *name* for the address of the array, not a pointer that can change. So you have to use `memcpy` to copy the elements.

Comment: What's wrong with brace initializers - when used correctly, of course? Why are they confusing?

Comment: It's confusing *here* because it's initializing an array, not a scalar. (E.g.: Is it assigning a value to the first element? Or to the entire array? Does it even compile? If not, is it because you can't assign a pointer to a `char`, or because of something else? It makes the reader think too much.)

I don't like them in general for other reasons, but that's just personal taste; in this particular case, though, I think they're best avoided.

Comment: Thanks - memcpy seems like a decent solution. My only other concern is that if I change MEM_SIZE to something large, would doing the copy take a noticeable amount of time?

Comment: It would take the same amount of time as any other method -- the amount of time needed to copy the array. If you want to avoid the copying, use a pointer instead of an array. :)

Comment: Obviously it's not correct in this case because the initializer itself is wrong but it sounded like you were recommending against initializing arrays at all and always using `memcpy` to populate them.

Comment: Haha no I wasn't, that wasn't what I was trying to say (although I can see why it implied that), even though it's true that they're not my favorite coding practice. I was referring to the initialization of array members using brace initializers, not all brace initializations in general.

Comment: OK, but I'm still curious. What's special about arrays, what's wrong with initializing them with brace enclosed initializers?

Comment: See the examples in my second comment.

Comment: I don't think that the rules are as complicated as you are making them out to be. Either that or I don't understand your argument. Also you said "for other reasons" which just made me curious.

Comment: To me, it's like saying something like `while (i < j) *pp[++i]++;` in your code. The rules might not be that complicated, but I'd argue that it's better practice to instead write something like: `while (i < j) { ++i; (*pp[i])++; }`, even if they're both readable and not too difficult to figure out. The whole point of *good code* is to let the reader spend his thinking on deciphering your steps and your algorithm, not on deciphering the syntax or the semantics of your language, whether they're straightforward or not.

Comment: (I ran out of room above, so more here...)
As for the "other reasons", I was referring to the fact that code like this would **easily** break if the struct members were for any reason rearranged or altered (say, if another field is added or one removed), and that alone is reason enough for me to avoid this. I'm just curious, don't you think that's a good reason to (generally) avoid code like this? :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use memcpy to copy data
2. Allocate new memory in func init, the 'chip' will be recovered when the func init end.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above are recommended ways of copying data from a buffer into a contained buffer defined in a struct.

And, to answer your question - yes.
You're initializing the array with the pointer value.  Initializing the array like you did in main with "memory":
char memory[MAX_SIZE] = { 0 }; // array intialization.

Performing a memcpy() is the preferred way of doing this.  Also - it's bad practice returning a local struct from a function - the preferred way is to allocate an object on the heap and do a memcpy.  (Though the compiler could optimise this out - with the extra copying) It's just horrible practice.

If you know the structure of the array at compile time:
Other possibilities are c99 struct initializations (usually done within kernel mode):
mem_t memObj = {
   .mem = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
};
or simply: mem_t memObj = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; (in your example, since it's the only member)

Note: When doing array initializations, it's similar to zero'ing out the rest of the elements in the array - could be not what you were expecting/wanted.

Comment: Why is it considered bad practice to return a local struct?

Comment: Technically - you'd want to pass in a struct to fill by ptr/ref.  You're copying the entire struct object if you return a struct from a function.

Answer (score 0):

For your struct you can use the implicit struct-content-copy like:

```
mem init(char *prog){
 return *(mem*)prog;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 char memory[MEM_SIZE] = {0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD}; /* non zero test values */

 mem chip = init(memory);
 printf("%02X%02X%02X%02X\n",chip.mem[0],chip.mem[1],chip.mem[2],chip.mem[3]);

 memory[1]=0;
 chip = init(memory);
 printf("%02X%02X%02X%02X\n",chip.mem[0],chip.mem[1],chip.mem[2],chip.mem[3]);

 return 0;
}
```